# How do you pass multiple arguments to __setstate__?

Tags: python

I am doing deepcopy on a class I designed, which has multiple lists as attributes to it.  With a single list, this is solvable by overriding **getstate** to return that list, and **setstate** to set that list, but **setstate** seems unable to take multiple parameters.

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have `__getstate__` return (and `__setstate__` accept) a list of lists, or a `dict` (if you implement `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`, `__getstate__` doesn't have to return a `dict`)

```
import pickle

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list1 = [1]
        self.list2 = [2]

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {'list1': self.list1, 'list2': self.list2}

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.list1 = state['list1']
        self.list2 = state['list2']

ex = Example()
s = pickle.dumps(ex)
ex2 = pickle.loads(s)
print ex.list1, ex.list2
```

This is just a demo.  You really don't even need to override pickle's default behavior for a simple case like this.

Comment: Ah, awesome!  Didn't know you could lay out the getstate like that.  Thanks a ton